# Make a live Linux reload data into block cache from live DVD

Tags: livecd, dvd

I eject the DVD, attempt starting Firefox, and put the DVD back in.

Firefox did not start, **but even after inserting the live DVD disc back, Firefox was still returning an input/output error.**

Apparantly, it is still considering the data as unreadable.

`sudo sh -c 'echo 1 >>/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'` just made everything worse: not loading from DVD, just wiping the cache.

How do I force Linux to reload previously errornous data from the DVD?

Comment: Could you discover the DVD content after insert DVD back?

Comment: @YurijGoncharul Yes.